# Calcular en input TOTAL según ingreso de datos en otros input

Tags: javascript

Tengo 3 input (Ancho, Largo y Alto) y en un cuarto input (Total), necesito por favor, que al estar todos los 3 primeros con valores el último se llene con la fórmula:
.

Ancho x Largo x Alto = Total

Es decir, si alguno de los 3 primero input esta vacío la formula no se procese pero apenas detecte que todos estan llenos proceda a hacer la formula.

Mi HTML es este:

```
<div>
    <label>Ancho</label>
    <input type="text" id="ancho" name="ancho" onkeypress="return NumCheck(event, this)">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Largo</label>
    <input type="text" id="largo" name="largo" onkeypress="return NumCheck(event, this)">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Alto</label>
    <input type="text" id="alto" name="alto" onkeypress="return NumCheck(event, this)">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Total</label>
    <input type="text" id="total" name="total">
</div>
```

Adicional a esto tengo una función para validar que el valor ingresado sea solo numerico de 5 cifras y 4 decimales (12345,1234):

```
function NumCheck(e, field) {
key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which

// backspace
if (key == 8) return true

// 0-9
if (key > 47 && key < 58) {
if (field.value == "") return true
regexp = /.[0-9]{4}$/

return !(regexp.test(field.value))
}

// .
if (key == 44) {

if (field.value == "") return false
regexp = /^[0-9]+$/

return regexp.test(field.value)
}

// other key
return false
}
```

Que me funciona a la perfección pero no se si me esta interrumpiendo las pruebas que estuve haciendo.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "no se si me esta interrumpiendo las pruebas que estuve haciendo."?

Comment: Es que estuve colocando un pequeño fragmento de codigo a ver si lograba construir la función que necesito y esto hizo que esa función NumCheck no me funcionara. Pero ya le quite y por el momento tengo el codigo tal cual esta formulado en la pregunta

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta porque no está claro lo que estás preguntando.

Answer (score 4):

**Acá te comparto un ejemplo que cumple con lo siguiente:**

- Los inputs tienen que ser numéricos
- Solamente se multiplican los 3 inputs si se cumplen todas las validaciones
- Si no se cumplen las validaciones el input del resultado se reinicia y su valor es vacio.
- Tiene soporte para conservar los primeros 5 números y 4 decimales

**Ejemplo online:**
https://jsfiddle.net/chenay01/2yuskq6f/132

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <label>Ancho</label>
  <input class="numero" type="number" id="ancho" name="ancho">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Largo</label>
  <input class="numero" type="number" id="largo" name="largo">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Alto</label>
  <input class="numero" type="number" id="alto" name="alto">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Total</label>
  <input type="number" id="total" name="total" disabled>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var numeros = document.querySelectorAll('.numero');
var total = document.getElementById('total');

function validarTecla(e) {
  var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  var value = e.target.value;
  var valores = value.split('.');
  var posicionCursor = e.target.selectionStart;
  var indicePunto = value.indexOf('.');

  // 0-9
  if (key > 47 && key < 58) {
    if (indicePunto > -1) {
      if (posicionCursor <= indicePunto) {
        return valores[0] && valores[0].length < 5;
      } else {
        return valores[1] && valores[1].length < 4;
      }
    } else {
        return valores[0].length < 5;
    }
  }

  // .
  if (key === 46 && !/\./.test(value)) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

function calcular(e) {
  var calculo = 1;
  var esValido = true;

  numeros.forEach(n => {
    if (!esValido) {
      return;
    }

    if (!n.value) {
      esValido = false;
      return;
    }

    calculo = calculo * Number(n.value);
  })


  if (esValido) {
    total.value = parseFloat(calculo.toFixed(4));
  } else {
    total.value = '';
  }
}

numeros.forEach(n => {
  n.onkeypress = validarTecla;
  n.onkeyup = calcular;
});
```

Comment: Funciona exclente, pero no suma cuando introduzco cifras con decimales... pense que era porque habia cambiado el punto "." por coma "," pero si colocando el punto realiza la suma

Comment: @roberthung creo que la respuesta es válida por lo que dices más bien es una mejora en la que tú debes trabajar y no exigir recuerda que uno solo espera es un +1 y una respuesta aceptada

Comment: @roberthung ahi quedo actualizado el código para soportar decimales así como se agrego otra función que mejora las validaciones.

Answer (score 0):

*He realizado unos ajustes en tu código para cumplir con lo que comentas, ten en cuenta que el numero con decimales se trata con el punto el cual el keyCode es el 46, el 44 es para la coma*:

```js
function NumCheck(e, field) {
  var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  var regexp;

  // backspace
  if (key == 8) return true;

  // 0-9
  if (key > 47 && key < 58) {
    if (field.value == "") return true;
    regexp = /.[0-9]{4}$/;

    return !(regexp.test(field.value));
  }

  // .
  if (key == 46) {

    if (field.value == "") return false;
    regexp = /^[0-9]+$/;

    return regexp.test(field.value);
  }

  // other key
  return false;
}

function verifyInput(field) {
  if (field.value.trim() != '' && /^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$/.test(field.value)) {
    var valor = field.value.split('.');
    if (valor.length == 2 && valor[0].length == 5 && valor[1].length == 4) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function calculartotal(ancho, largo, alto) {
  var elementoTotal = document.getElementById('total');
  if (verifyInput(ancho) && verifyInput(largo) && verifyInput(alto)) {
    var total = Number(ancho.value) * Number(largo.value) * Number(alto.value);
    elementoTotal.value = total + '';
  } else {
    elementoTotal.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <label>Ancho</label>
  <input type="text" id="ancho" name="ancho" onkeypress="return NumCheck(event, this)" onkeyup="calculartotal(this, largo, alto)" #ancho>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Largo</label>
  <input type="text" id="largo" name="largo" onkeypress="return NumCheck(event, this)" onkeyup="calculartotal(ancho, this, alto)" #largo>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Alto</label>
  <input type="text" id="alto" name="alto" onkeypress="return NumCheck(event, this)" onkeyup="calculartotal(ancho, largo, this)" #alto>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Total</label>
  <input type="text" id="total" name="total">
</div>
```

*Espero te sirva*

Comment: No veo que el input de total se llene con el resultado

Comment: Disculpa @jorge pero no me funcionó el código en ambos requerimientos. Los input se pueden llenar incluso con letras y no llena el resultado final

Comment: @roberthung a ok, en el caso de no rellenarlos con letras si toca ajustarlo, pero en el caso del total, según lo que pediste si funciona. debes ingresar los 5 digitos iniciales seguido del punto y por ultimo los 4 decimales, si no lo haces así no te va a funcionar el total. Ya te ajusto el tema de los datos que no permita cualquier cosa el input